# xtreg, re in STATA, which R2 to report?

Tags: stata, panel-data, random-effects-model, r-squared, generalized-least-squares

After estimating the data using xtreg, re, I notice there're 3 different measures of R-squared, within, between, and overall R-2, so my question is, can I just report the overall R2 in this case since I'm using the random effects option? Thanks.